# Django: use update_or_create having the foreign key value but not a foreign key object instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have a data from a raw sql query which has records that look like this:

"product_id": 12345
"date": 2022-12-25
"qty": 10

this is to go into a table with model "ProductMovement".
Its unique key is product_id and date.
product_movement has product_id as a foreign key to the Product model.

`ProductMovement.objects.update_or_create()` requires me to provide an instance of the Product model, not merely the unique key. This is inconvenient.

I guess I can use raw sql (backend is postgresql) but I wonder if there is another way. Can I add something to the model manager that intercepts the key value and replaces it with the instance, so at least I can hide this complexity from this part of the code? (I have never worked with model manager overrides).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you use the '_id' version of the ProductMovement product column, eg, ProductMovement.objects.update_or_create(product_id = record['product_id'], date = record['date'])?

Comment: No you are not missing something, I am. I have code that rewrites the fields names as necessary for the default values but I had a bug when foreign keys were detected; they were not renamed for the matching columns. When I included them in that logic, it worked (the key in source misses the _id suffix). Write up a quick answer and I will tick it. Thanks for your comment, it encouraged me to look again at my code.

Answer (score 2):

###### Try this first

If you're command looks like this `ProductMovement.objects.update_or_create(product=productObj)` **has no _id**
Try running it like `ProductMovement.objects.update_or_create(product_id=12345)` **with _id**

###### Manager

Yea! You can override the `update_or_create` function- I've done it for filters/gets to fetch M2M relations easier

```py
class ProductMovementManager(models.Manager):
    def update_or_create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = kwargs.pop('product')
        if type(product) == int:
            kwargs['product'] = Product.objects.filter(pk=product).first()
        else:
            # oops! It was already the object
            kwargs['product'] = product

        super().update_or_create(*args, **kwargs)

class ProductMovement(models.Model)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    objects = ProductMovementManager()
```

Comment: thank you . My problem was simpler than this, but this is a practical and interesting example which I look forward to using.